# Installing package taking time in DayCQ

Tags: aem

When I try to upload my packages through package manager, it goes into infinite loop. And if I  refresh the page it finishes immediately. But I can not access the content. 
I am new to CQ, but I believe it should not take this much time. Is there anything which I am missing or something that can be wrong ?

Comment: Question is too vague to tell what might be the issue. Please post the logs or add additional info regarding the package, which might help others in understanding the problem.

Comment: @Rakhi I dont have much information currently I have put whatever I knew. :( could you please let me know how to check logs

Comment: When you are installing the package through Package Manager, you will find the Activity Log below. Also, you can find the error log in the below path <<serverpath on your hardisk>>\crx-quickstart\logs\error.log

Comment: What CQ version are you using?

Comment: @Thomas version is  5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take so much time in the next case.
When you upload a package, package content merges with paths that have already existed in your JCR. Therefore, if your content restricts by path with the same nodes in CQ, CQ will try to merge it. In case then CQ already have a lot of nodes by restricting paths this process can take a while even if your package is small.